# Parallelism execution from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with thousand of queries are waiting for execute in sql server. I am using an store procedure to execute those queries one by one. Is there any way that I can execute those queries in parallel to make the store procedure running more faster?

Comment: Queries waiting for execute (SELECT or DELETE/INSERT/UPDATE)?

Comment: You could write a simple asynchronous .NET application to query the queries and execute them in parallel: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: Is there any queries that I just need to add into my current store procedure?